# How to bind name to router-outlet

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm trying to do something like

```
<router-outlet name='chart.id'></router-outlet>
```

where chart.id is something like "id1, id2, id3", etc. I would like to generate these at runtime because I do not know how many ids I will have.

I would like the end result to be like

```
<router-outlet name='id1'></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name='id2'></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name='id3'></router-outlet>
```

Thanks!

Comment: try this `[name]='chart.id'` or `name={{chart.id}}`

Comment: i get a template parse error since name is not a known property of router-outlet

Comment: Okay then try this one `[attr.name]='chart.id'`

Comment: Ahh, I just tried that. Nothing still :( . I read through router-outlet's source code on github, name is a private attribute of router-outlet. So I don't think you can bind it as a property.

Comment: Ohh may be I  am not sure about that. !!

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it right now but it's a requested feature.

You can check it [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12522)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I'm using **Angular 6.0.0**. Since this doesn't seem to be supported yet, I've created a workaround with a directive, which wraps around the original `RouterOutlet`. I know this goes against many rules for angular, but I really needed to pass the name dynamically:

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef, ComponentFactoryResolver, Directive, Input, OnDestroy, OnInit, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ChildrenOutletContexts, RouterOutlet as NgRouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';

@Directive({
  selector: 'custom-router-outler',
  exportAs: 'outlet'
})
export class RouterOutlet implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  public original: NgRouterOutlet;
  private _name: string;

  // I don't know about the side effects, if this gets changed, so 
  // this throws an error if the name gets changed twice. Yes 
  // I'm not proud of myself. This is too ugly :(
  public set name(name: string) {
    if (this._name) {
      throw new Error('The name of an outlet can\'t be changed');
    }

    this._name = name;
  }

  constructor(
    private parentContexts: ChildrenOutletContexts,
    private location: ViewContainerRef,
    private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) {

  }

  public ngOnInit() {
    this.original = new NgRouterOutlet(this.parentContexts, this.location, this.resolver, this._name, this.changeDetector);
    this.original.ngOnInit();
  }

  public ngOnDestroy() {
    this.original.ngOnDestroy();
  }
}
```

Maybe someone finds it helpful until this feature is implemented by default.